# using finally: to remove temporary variables defined in try: except: block

Tags: python

I am using python error handling instructions. In my script I have some `try` blocks were some temporary variables are used, it similarly holds for the `except` blocks.

I would like to use the `del` statement (or something similar) within a `finally` block to clean out all the vars created within the `try` and `except` ones.

The problem is that I don't know exactly a priori which are the created ones since I don't know whether the program will possibly fail.

Is there an elegant way to get it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Like @jonrsharpe I'm also wondering *why* you want to do this and *why* you don't know what those variables are? That being said a very simple method would to put the whole thing in a function and call it - then let the garbage collector do its work when the function completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the `locals()` dict and compare the before and after to see what you need to remove. This is probably frowned upon, but it should do what you want.

```
a = 3
b = '4'

snapshot = None # make sure snapshot is included in itself
snapshot = locals().copy()
try:
    c = 5
    assert False
except AssertionError:
    d = []
finally:
    for variable in list(locals()):
        if variable not in snapshot:
            del locals()[variable]
    del locals()['snapshot'] # optional

assert 'a' in locals()
assert 'b' in locals()
assert 'c' not in locals()
assert 'd' not in locals()
assert 'snapshot' not in locals()
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you could check for the existence of the variables using `locals()`, but the question remains why you would want to do that.

A reason I can imagine is that you want to ensure that the memory for a large object that is no longer needed is released. To do that, you can simply assign `None` to the variable.

```
try:
    a = VeryLargeObject()
    b = AnotherVeryLargeObject()
    ...
finally:
    a = b = None
```

However, if this code is encapsulated in a function, the memory is released anyway as soon as the function returns.

That being said, I would not clutter my code with manual "memory management" unless you run into actual memory issues.

**Edit:** after @JonClements comment, I want to clarify: assigning `None` to a name, just like `del`, doesn't actually remove the object referenced by a name, it just removes the reference. In this example, the object `a` referred to would not be released, because there is still referenced from the global list:

```
global_list = []

try:
    a = VeryLargeObject()
    global_list.append(a)
    b = AnotherVeryLargeObject()
    ...
finally:
    a = b = None
```

Comment: Objects will be freed if no other references to the objects exist. Assigning None to names doesn't guarantee that. Also - from what I can gather the OP doesn't know there's an 'a' or 'b' to do this to anyway... But yes - putting this in a function by itself alleviates most of these concerns (as would structuring the handling in such a way it's deterministic)

Comment: @JonClements my understanding of the question is that the variable names are known, but it is not known where the exception is raised (e.g. in my example before `b` is assigned). You are correct that assigning `None` only frees the object when no other references exist (but so does `del`eting the name). I will expand my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Indeed. However, until the OP clarifies - my gut feeling is none of this is/should be necessary...